# Is it acceptable to talk about instances of an abstract class?

Tags: uml, modeling, object-oriented-analysis

I am part of a working group that is developing an IEEE standard.  The problem domain of the standard is expressed as an object-oriented model.  The model is independent of any particular implementation language but does use UML to express aspects of the model.  In many places in the text there are references to "instances of Foo" where Foo is an abstract class.  What is really meant is, "instances of any instantiable subclass of Foo".

It has always been my experience that the "instances of Foo" was understood to mean "instances of any instantiable subclass of Foo".  Is this understanding something that most people versed in object-oriented models would share?  If so, is there some good reference that we can point to that would support this understanding?  If this isn't something that is commonly understood then we need to change a lot of text, but that's the way it goes.

Answer (score 1):

The question has two aspects, firt what is correct in senso of UML and second how is it understood in reality. 
Let us start with the simpler aspect. The UML standard clearly states that any instance of a classifier is also an instance of any of its generalizations

> An instance of a Classifier is also an (indirect) instance of each of
>   its generalizations. Any Constraints applying to instances of the
>   generalizations also apply to instances of the Classifier.

This just gives a very static view on it. But and is not the compelete answer, because it does not say anything about how the instances can be used dynamically. But the standard also states that any instance can be used as an instance of any its generalized classifiers:

> Type conformance means that if one Type conforms to another, then any
>   instance of the first Type may be used as the value of a TypedElement
>   whose type is declared to be the second Type. A Classifier is a Type,
>   and conforms to itself and to all of its generalizations.

So in that case the standard is quite clear.

Second aspect, the reality. In reality most of the practically applied OOP languages support polymorphism. Simplified spoken, any object of class can be treated as if it were an object of any of its super classes. Thus most people intepretete it like you meant it.

Therefore I would propose to use it in the proposed way in your standard and additionally write this in an introductionary chapter as an help for interpretation.

All refernces are to OMG UML 2.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Having just gone back (again) to the OMG standard for UML and searched through it again I found this text:

> An instance of a Classifier is also an (indirect) instance of each of
>   its generalizations.

Furthermore, in clause 9.7.5 it uses the text

> each instance of Person

in reference to a model shown in Figure 9.22.
[image]

In Figure 9.22, class *Person* is abstract.  I think this pretty clearly resolves this in favor of , "instances of Foo," being completely correct and acceptable.

Comment: @ThomasKilian  You aren't correct.  Please see my edited answer.  A) There is no statement that instances of a classifier are also instances of their generalization *if and only if* the generalization is concrete (i.e. instantiable) and B) if the authors of the standard are referring to "instances of" an abstract class then I am confident that I am correct.

Comment: The dissension is actually quite helpful.  Even if it isn't technically wrong (with respect to the OMG standard), the fact that it isn't obvious and commonly understood does lead me to want to add some text to our standard that clarifies the situation for readers.

Comment: @ThomasKilian You are missing the point.  The question is not, "Can I instantiate class Person?".  I never suggested that one could do so.  The question was whether it is acceptable to refer to 'instances of Person?'.  The answer, based on the standard for UML, is that it is reasonable to do so.

Comment: I get that you can't instantiate an abstract class.  What you can do is refer to, for example, a collection of instances of subclasses of an abstract class by the name of that abstract class.  If Person is abstract and subclassed by Man and Woman (both concrete) then I can refer to "instances of Person" to describe a collection of Men and Women.  If I am wrong about this then so are the authors of the UML standard because they do *exactly* what I am describing in the example in clause 9.7.5 (of the most recent version of the standard). Are you suggesting that the UML standard is wrong?